# WordPress Keeps redirecting to the old development server IP Address instead of the new development IP Address

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am little bit newbie for WordPress.  I have been developing website on my local machine using word press but it has come to a time where we have to migrate the website to client server with a public IP address. The computer is behind router. All the port forwarding are done. I even manage to access wp-admin page. However when I tried to access the main website I can't because it keeps redirecting the public IP to a local IP or to the first development IP address. Note that I have changed the general setting to the public IP address.

Thank you for your help

Comment: @CyC0der Thank you very much. The article on the link provided worked very well. The title in the article was "Uploading A WordPress Website From A Local To A Remote Installation #"  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/moving-wordpress-website/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for answer here is the link I find my answer from.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/moving-wordpress-website/

Specifically on the title "Uploading A WordPress Website From A Local To A Remote Installation #"

Thank you @CyC0der for pointing out the article